# .htaccess redirect destroys sessions due to pre-page load?

Tags: php, .htaccess, session, redirect

My .htaccess file redirects my page to a https connections and some more redirects whenever needed.

However, I have a script which checks wheter a session is set (PHP). If so, I perform a visual action and unset the session. However, when the .htaccess kicks in with its redirects, I see the visual effect for a millisecond and on the fresh redirect from the .htaccess, the effect is gone, because the session is already unset...

I hope it's clear enough, quit a strange story but yea... it seems to happen untill now :(

Thanks for any help in advance!

P.S. simple structure:

1). Loading page -> do visual and unset session

2). .HTACCESS kicks in with the redirect to https

3). Loading page -> ***NO visual due to an already unset session in first step***

Comment: htaccess will be processed before php is even called at all. If the htaccess redirects, php isn't loaded for that request, the browser is redirected and then a new request is made for the redirected-to page.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that requests made to http and https are completely separate requests, same as if they were completely different servers. If you created a session over http, it will not be available to the site running over https. The session cookie set over http will not be passed over https and so the session will not resume.

Comment: Jonathan, thanks for The fast replies. However, I am almost sure my page gets loaded prior to redirection. My .htaccess file is fine, since safari works as expected. However, it seems like a bug in both chrome and Firefox that the page is loaded prior to redirect...

Comment: Then it isn't the htaccess file that is doing the redirect. Can you provide a the htaccess file and maybe the initial loading page ([mcve]). If you are seeing the page loading prior to redirect, I would assume it is the page that is loading that does the redirect (meta tag or javascript), not htaccess. You aren't providing any code to check so we just get to guess what is actually happening based on what you say you are doing which isn't adding up.

Comment: Also, you can try to open the developer tools in the browser(s) with an issue, go to the network tab, turn on the preserve on redirect option and hit the expected site. You can view each request along with what headers and content were sent out and actually see what was doing the redirect as opposed to just guessing and assuming.

Comment: Jonathan, despite the missing example you are pushing me the right way I think. Out of the top of my head, I indeed think I have redirect page running in php. Silly me... I will check it tomorrow, because I think you are right about the fact that this page is actually redirecting. But still, the redirect is done in PHP which is executed line by line so the redirect should interrupt the normal page flow, however I will verify it tomorrow. Thanks for your reactions, very helpful!

Comment: PHP doesn't interrupt the page flow on a redirect. If the redirect is happening on the server (call to `header()`), then all code up to the redirect is run and if you don't exit after the redirect, the remaining code can still finish running (depending on your server settings). If you are redirecting on client side (javascript or meta refresh), then all php code is run and the results sent to the client. The flow doesn't change at all. Then after some amount of time the browser makes a new request for the next page.

Comment: Yea I know, but I use header followed by an exit if inredirect that's for sure. The redirect won't happen on client side thx for pushing me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

use this example at the end of your htaccess
if you want redirect non ssl then remove https:// and put http://

if you want to use subfolder to be redirected use following code

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} subfoldername
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yourdomain.com/subfoldername$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is no answer for the asked question at all. My .htaccess file works fine on safari and that's why I don't doubt about my .htaccess file. Besides that, I have made many more .htaccess files, so I know how they have to be set-up to redirect https etc. Thanks for your reply though